# Is there anyway to create graphical representation lets say 2D by PHP?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1

I'm sure, I don't ask for the whole script. If you have answer == Yes then Please provide the function names in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). It has functions for processing images, as well as for drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `gd library`

More on :
     http://www.php.net/image
and
    http://www.php.net/imagick

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is really what you are searching for but the documentation of php should be able to tell you more.

For example:
http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php